# Turn off terminal logs when debugging C++ programs in Visual Studio Code on Macbook

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

These are automatically printed at the front when I debug and run any C++ program

```
Working directory: '/Users/xxx/C++'
1 arguments:
argv[0] = 'Users/xxx/C++/program'
```

Don't know why they're there and didn't find a way to turn them off

It happens across different Macs debugging with the official C/C++ extension and using Terminal.app as external console, are there any actions that I can take to prevent these logs from printing?

Edit 1:
These are shown in the integrated terminal after building:

```
Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

It definitely closes itself when catching any keystrokes and it's the only terminal that's opened.

In the debug console it's waiting for input I can't find where to input

Comment: are you using a particular VS Code extension to run the program? Did you use any particular CLI library in this program?

Comment: No and no I'm afraid, I'm just setting up a fresh environment with only the C/C++ extension by Microsoft installed

Comment: what debugger are you using? did you do anything to your debugger's configuration that could be causing this?

Comment: Don't think I've adjusted anything after installing clang from Xcode on the two Macs that I've tested, but got the same result. The logs definitely looks like some default messages though but I tried different log levels in launch.json but it doesn't affect these lines

Comment: does it happen if you use the integrated terminal for the launch config instead of an external terminal?

Comment: It seems to be a problem that hitting debug and run with "externalConsole": false, the integrated terminal only shows build logs but do not output anything regarding to the program, no logs no cout strings, and shows no sign of the program running

Comment: did you check the debug panel?

Comment: the debug console does show the output strings, but can't be used for cin/input, that's what made me use external console in the first place sadly

Comment: don't you just need o switch to the terminal panel to do the input?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what does the "o switch to the terminal" meant, as for typing input in the terminal I edited the original post to explain what happens